# No wireless on my Dell Inspiron 1545 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I had installed Ubuntu 12.10 a few months back but never really used wireless device. I did use wireless before that when I had windows installed on my Dell, but then I switched to Ubuntu and the option for Wireless never worked. I used to work with LAN network till now and that worked just fine, but now since I have relocated, I have dongle for my internet but now I want to share this over a wireless network which I am unable to figure out.

Here's a couple of things that may help regarding this :

The snapshot [image] shows no wireless option here.

Also the result of `lshw -class network`

is

```
 *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 13
   serial: 00:23:ae:34:46:d2
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp     10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2     driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:45 memory:f69fc000-f69fffff ioport:de00(size=256)
```

**EDIT 1 **

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory     Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset     Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset     Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI     Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI     Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI     Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI     Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio     Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port     1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port     2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port     3 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port     5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI     Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI     Controller #2 (rev 03) 
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI     Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI     Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev     03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4     port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev     03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E     Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
```

Comment: Show us `lspci`.

Comment: @Kwpolska Did so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like your laptop isn't detecting the wireless hardware correctly. You can triage this a couple of ways.

First take a look in `/var/log/syslog` and the output from the command `dmesg` looking for any mention of the manufacturer of the dongle you mentioned in your question.

If there is no mention then Linux isn't able to recognize your hardware. So the next thing to do would be to go to the manufacturer's website to see if they offer a Linux driver. If so download it on another computer and bring it over via USB thumbdrive and install it per their directions.

If there isn't any driver available on their site then you'll have to see if you can find a driver that's compatible with your dongle. This can be done in a few ways, one way would be to try and determine specifics about the hardware. Are there any model #'s or markings on it that you can google for?

Also if it's a USB device you might have some luck in using the `lsusb` command adding more verbose switches, `lsusb -vvv` to try and get more info out of the system about the hardware.

**NOTE:** You can do the same with `lspci`, i.e. `lspci -vvv` as well.

Ultimately if you can get something that identifies the hardware such as it's PCI address you can look up this hardware to find out what drivers support it.

#### For example

Here's the output from the Ethernet device. Using the following switches you can find out it's PCI address and look it up on a site such as [PCI ID Repository](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC), for example, [here's mine](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10ec/8168).

```
$ lspci -vn
02:00.0 0200: 10ec:8168 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: 1849:8168
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Memory at fdfff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fdff8000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at febe0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [cc] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 03-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Incidentally, if you notice the last 2 lines show you what drivers this device is using. Also the PCI address of this device, **10ec:8168**, is part of the output from the first line of output:

> 02:00.0 0200: 10ec:8168 (rev 03)

#### Using another distro to find it

If you're completely desperate or lazy you can but the system up using another distro that you know this device works in, or perhaps a LiveCD distro, and run the above command to see what driver they're using, and then come back to Ubuntu and manually force that driver there as well.